# Define $S(v+null T) = Tv $ where $S:V/(nullT) \rightarrow W$ and $T: V \rightarrow W$. Show $S$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Define $S(v+ \mathrm{null}T) = Tv$ where $S:V/(\mathrm{null}T) \rightarrow W$ and $T: V \rightarrow W$ and $v\in V$.
Show $S$ is injective.

This comes up with on Page 98 of Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd edition as an example.

I'm having a hard time with the last step.

> The proof says: Suppose $v \in V$ and $S(v + \mathrm{null}T)=0$. Then
>   $Tv=0$. Thus $v \in \mathrm{null}T$. Hence 3.85 implies that
>   $v+\mathrm{null}T = 0 + \mathrm{null}T$. This implies that null$S$ =0,
>   and hence $S$ is injective.

Specifically, I can't see why $v+\mathrm{null}T = 0 + \mathrm{null}T$ implies null$S$ =0

For reference, 3.85 states:

> Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $v,w \in V$. Then the following
>   are equivalent: a) $v-w \in U$ ; b) $v+U=w+U$ ; c) $(v+U)\cap(w+U) \neq \emptyset $

Comment: The definition of $S$ above is quoted incorrectly from Linear Algebra Done Right. The definition given in the book is that $S(v + \text{null } T) = Tv$.

Comment: @SheldonAxler Thank you. It's fixed. And thanks for writing a great book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He started with an arbitrary vector $v + \operatorname{null} T\in \operatorname{null} S$ and showed that the vector must be the zero vector of $V/\operatorname{null} T$, i.e., $0 + \operatorname{null} T$. Thus, the only possible element of $\operatorname{null} S$ is $0 + \operatorname{null} T$. Since $0 + \operatorname{null} T$ is already in $\operatorname{null} S$, you deduce that $\operatorname{null} S = \{0 + \operatorname{null} T\}$ (here he simply writes $\operatorname{null} S = 0$).

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little confused. I guess where I'm having trouble is the concept of a zero vector in a quotient space. I understand that the additive identity in a quotient space $V/U$ is $0+U$ or $U$.  So i'm following what you're saying up to $\operatorname{null} S \subset \{0 + \operatorname{null} T\}$. What I don't understand is the sentence after....

Comment: I get that the zero vector is in any subspace, but isn't the zero vector of $V/ \operatorname{null} T$ this: $0 + \operatorname{null} T$ ? In other words, since the domain of $S$ is $V/ \operatorname{null} T$, then the additive identity of the domain is in a subspace of it (here, specifically, null S). Then shouldn't it be $0 + \operatorname{null} T \subset \operatorname{null} S$? Shouldn't this give us nullS = null T? How did we get null S =0?

Comment: @Snowball read the edited answer. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I understand this proof now, but will still need to wrap my head around how a non-trivial subspace $U$ of $V$ when viewed in the context of the vector space $V$ has non-zero dimension, but if viewed in the context of a vector space $V/U$ has zero dimension. I think this is the first example I've encountered that I can think of where the dimension of a subspace is not "fixed".

Comment: Well, quotienting by a subspace gives a "smaller" space, e.g., if $U = V$, then $V/U = 0$. More generally, if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then $\operatorname{dim} V/U = \operatorname{dim} V - \operatorname{dim} U$. For if $\{u_1,\ldots, u_k\}$ is a basis of $U$, you can extend it to a basis $\{u_1,\ldots, u_k, v_{k+1},\ldots, v_{k+l}\}$ of $V$. You can then show that $\{v_{k+1} + U,\ldots, v_{k+l} + U\}$ is a basis for $V/U$, proving $\operatorname{dim} V/U = l = \operatorname{dim} V - \operatorname{dim} U$.